# Angular: Unit Testing - Not able to test Ternary branch for code coverage

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a ternary branch which is using `window.location`.

```
@Injectable()
export class ABCService {
  private hostUrl = (window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') > -1) ? 'example.com' : window.location.host;
...
```

TestCase:

```
it('check alternate URL', () => {
        const URL = 'http://example.org/postMethod';
        service.getData().subscribe(data => {
            expect(data.length).toBe(1);
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne(URL);
        expect(req.request.url).toBe(URL);
        req.flush({data:[1]});
    });
```

Getting Error:

```
   Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://example.org/postMethod", found none.
```

Any ideas of how can I test if `window.location.host` is not localhost.
Tried  `(window as any).location = { ...window.location, host: 'http://example.org' };`
still getting host == `localhost:9876;` 
**OR**
Is there any way I can override `window.location.host` value of mock it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of referencing a global variable, which might not be defined depending on what environment you are running your app in (e.g. Angular Universal), use dependency injection.

In this case you can get the information you want from Angular's DOCUMENT constant (https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT).

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc) {
  console.log(this.doc.location.href);
}
```

And in your tests you could mock it with:

```
const service = new ABCService({location: {href: 'my-test-url'}} as any);
```

Comment: +1 See how testing works. Stops you from doing something that is a poor practice simply by forcing you to make it testable. :)

Answer (score 0):

I need to have the whole code to understand yor question and test case more accurately, can you please supply a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) url for it?

Anyway, you can use jasmine's `spyOn` function to mock window.location. Thisway you can supply mock it's functions and their return values, without actually setting the host.

Look at [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite) docs for more information.